# Keras in pip not installing

Tags: python, keras, pip

```
C:\Users\Hp>pip install keras
  Using cached Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)

  Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Have you installed hdf5 ?
`pip install h5py`

Comment: yes but   ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly